# Back up IMAP Server

Tags: email-server, imap

If I move to a hosted IMAP mail server solution (e.g. Google Apps) is there a way to have an on-site back up of the mail server that can be used as a local mail archive and backup solution?  What would I need to set up internally to achieve this?

A hosted solution is very attractive for a small company but With potential lose of internet connect I need my users to always get at their e-mail.

What are the options for such a hybrid mail solution?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using offlineimap + local dovecot server with some success for the same purpose.

However, note that offlineimap is not really meant for multiuser usage.

- http://software.complete.org/software/projects/show/offlineimap
- http://www.dovecot.org/

Comment: It might not be designed for multiuser, but it does the job admirably.

Answer (score 1):

Setup an IMAP server on your side and run [imapsync](http://freshmeat.net/projects/imapsync) periodically.